# How to access JSON objects in AJAX with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api

I'am doing a jquery call to API website, which returns me the results in JSON format:

```
{
  "results":[
    {
      "user":{
        "gender":"female",
        "name":{
          "title":"mrs",
          "first":"linda",
          "last":"diaz"
        },
        "location":{
          "street":"2333 oak lawn ave",
          "city":"red bluff",
          "state":"maryland",
          "zip":"49309"
        },
        "email":"linda.diaz55@example.com",
        "password":"blackman",
        "md5_hash":"3c64b82d048c8754a30e292a1359fa39",
        "sha1_hash":"d5095cf146dda75865d348f4ce4820b11b58b9fd",
        "phone":"(880)-878-1658",
        "cell":"(183)-179-1598",
        "SSN":"425-55-1070",
        "picture":"http:\/\/api.randomuser.me\/0.2\/portraits\/women\/8.jpg"
      },
      "seed":"2d589586d34c1c5",
      "version":"0.2.1"
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I access (or get values of) the items, for example: I want to `console.log()` the first name and the last name, get a phone number ?

Using a .(dot) not working for me, maybe i'am doing something wrong ?
Here is a javascript code

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url + resultsQuery,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: it's an array, so you'll need a combination of array notation and dot notation. Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: i tried to use `console.log(data.results[0].user)` but it returns me the `undefined`

Comment: if that returns undefined, the json isn't structured the way you think it is, that should have given you an object. Are you sure a user is getting returned at all?

Comment: @KevinB - it means, I'am doing something wrong or the JSON is not actually a real JSON format ?

Comment: What does `console.log(data);` give you?

Comment: It means either no users were returned with the request, or the json isn't in the structure you think it is. It's obviously json because otherwise you wouldn't have made it to the success callback.

Comment: @musefan - the OBJECT results (sorry, i don't know how to copy that information from my console)

Comment: @aspirinemaga: In chrome you can expand each object/array and see if all the information you expect is there

Comment: `console.log(data.results.length)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data.results[0].user.name.first
data.results[0].user.name.last
data.results[0].user.phone
```

Answer (score 2):

For your JSON Structure, try

```
 data.results[0].user.name.first
 data.results[0].user.name.last //etc
```